# Kurento: unable to apply GStreamer "audiocheblimit" + "cutter"

Tags: gstreamer, kurento

the following is my code block using which I am trying to remove noise from the incoming mediapipeline.

```
VADCustomFilterImpl::VADCustomFilterImpl(const boost::property_tree::ptree & config,std::shared_ptr <MediaPipeline > mediaPipeline) :FilterImpl (config,std::dynamic_pointer_cast <MediaObjectImpl> (mediaPipeline))
        {
            /* audio cheb limit - to remove noise */
            //GST_WARNING("------------------------audiocheblimit");
            g_object_set(element, "filter-factory", "audiocheblimit", NULL);
            g_object_get(G_OBJECT(element), "filter", &audiocheblimitfilter, NULL);

            if (audiocheblimitfilter == NULL) {
            throw KurentoException(MEDIA_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND, "MediaObject not found: audiocheblimitfilter");
            }

            g_object_set(G_OBJECT(audiocheblimitfilter), "mode", "low-pass", NULL);
            g_object_set(G_OBJECT(audiocheblimitfilter),"cutoff", 700, NULL);

            //GST_WARNING("----------------cutter");
            /*Cutter*/
            g_object_set(element, "filter-factory", "cutter", NULL);
            g_object_get(G_OBJECT(element), "filter", &cutterfilter, NULL);

            if (cutterfilter == NULL) {
                throw KurentoException(MEDIA_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND, "MediaObject not found: cutterfilter");
            }

            g_object_set(G_OBJECT(cutterfilter), "threshold-dB", -40.0, NULL);
            g_object_set(G_OBJECT(cutterfilter), "run-length", 500000000, NULL);

            //GST_WARNING("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~audiocheblimit+cutter");
            bus_handler_id = 0;

            g_object_unref(audiocheblimitfilter);
            g_object_unref(cutterfilter);
        }
```

in kurento logs only `------------------------audiocheblimit` is getting printed, after which there is no log and in my java server console  am getting `Websocket disconnected by WebSocket Read EOF (status code 1006)`

Is there any specific reason why this is crashing ?
Can we apply two GStreamer plugins one after another in kurento?

Or Do we need to create multiple kurento custom filters which will use one single GStreamer plugin in it??

**Edit 1:**

as pointed by @santoscadenas, I have looked into `faceoverlay` project and made changes accordingly in my code,

```
#include "gstvadcustomfilter.h"
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <glib/gstdio.h>
#include <gst/audio/audio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <cv.h>
#include <memory>

GST_DEBUG_CATEGORY_STATIC (gst_v_a_d_custom_filter_debug_category);
#define GST_CAT_DEFAULT gst_v_a_d_custom_filter_debug_category

#define PLUGIN_NAME "voicedetector"

#define GST_V_A_D_CUSTOM_FILTER_GET_PRIVATE(obj) (    \
    G_TYPE_INSTANCE_GET_PRIVATE (               \
        (obj),                                  \
        GST_TYPE_V_A_D_CUSTOM_FILTER,                 \
        GstVADCustomFilterPrivate                  \
                                )               \
                                           )

/* pad templates */

#define AUDIO_SRC_CAPS \
  GST_AUDIO_CAPS_MAKE("{ S16LE }")

#define AUDIO_SINK_CAPS \
  GST_AUDIO_CAPS_MAKE("{ S16LE }")

/* class initialization */
struct _GstVADCustomFilterPrivate
{
GstElement *audiocheb_limit;
GstElement *cutter_filter;
GstPad *src, *sink;
}priv;

//GstPad *tempsrc , *cuttersrcpad, *audiocheblimitsinkpad;

/* the capabilities of the inputs and outputs. */
GstStaticPadTemplate sink_factory = GST_STATIC_PAD_TEMPLATE ("sink",
    GST_PAD_SINK,
    GST_PAD_ALWAYS,
    GST_STATIC_CAPS (        // the capabilities of the padtemplate
        AUDIO_SINK_CAPS
      )
    );

GstStaticPadTemplate src_factory = GST_STATIC_PAD_TEMPLATE ("src",
    GST_PAD_SRC,
    GST_PAD_REQUEST,
    GST_STATIC_CAPS (        // the capabilities of the padtemplate
        AUDIO_SRC_CAPS
      )
    );

//G_DEFINE_TYPE (GstVADCustomFilter, gst_v_a_d_custom_filter, GST_TYPE_BIN);

G_DEFINE_TYPE_WITH_CODE (GstVADCustomFilter, gst_v_a_d_custom_filter,
                         GST_TYPE_BIN,
                         GST_DEBUG_CATEGORY_INIT (gst_v_a_d_custom_filter_debug_category,
                             PLUGIN_NAME, 0,
                             "debug category for v_a_d_custom_filter element") );


/*static GstFlowReturn
gst_v_a_d_custom_filter_transform_frame_ip (GstVideoFilter *filter,
                                      GstVideoFrame *frame)
{
GST_WARNING("gst_v_a_d_custom_filter_transform_frame_ip");
  return GST_FLOW_OK;
}*/

static void
gst_v_a_d_custom_filter_finalize (GObject *object)
{
GST_WARNING("Inside gst_v_a_d_custom_filter_finalize");
}

static void
gst_v_a_d_custom_filter_init (GstVADCustomFilter *v_a_d_custom_filter)
{
    GstPadTemplate *templ;
    GstPad *target;
    GST_ERROR("Inside gst_v_a_d_custom_filter_init");

    v_a_d_custom_filter->priv = GST_V_A_D_CUSTOM_FILTER_GET_PRIVATE (v_a_d_custom_filter);
    GST_ERROR("audio cheb limit");
    v_a_d_custom_filter->priv->audiocheb_limit =
    gst_element_factory_make ("audiocheblimit", NULL);

    g_object_set (v_a_d_custom_filter->priv->audiocheb_limit, "cutoff",700.0, NULL);

    gst_bin_add (GST_BIN (v_a_d_custom_filter), v_a_d_custom_filter->priv->audiocheb_limit);
    GST_ERROR("cutter");
    /*cutter*/
    v_a_d_custom_filter->priv->cutter_filter =
    gst_element_factory_make ("cutter", NULL);

    g_object_set (v_a_d_custom_filter->priv->cutter_filter, "threshold-dB",-40.0, NULL);
    g_object_set (v_a_d_custom_filter->priv->cutter_filter, "run-length",500000000, NULL);

    gst_bin_add (GST_BIN (v_a_d_custom_filter), v_a_d_custom_filter->priv->cutter_filter);
    GST_ERROR("cutter added to the bus");

    target = gst_element_get_static_pad (v_a_d_custom_filter->priv->audiocheb_limit, "sink");

    GST_ERROR("sink factory");
    templ = gst_static_pad_template_get (&sink_factory);
    GST_ERROR("sink , target, templ");

    v_a_d_custom_filter->priv->sink =
    gst_ghost_pad_new_from_template ("sink", target, templ);
    GST_ERROR("g_object_unref");
    g_object_unref (templ);
    g_object_unref (target);
    GST_ERROR("GST_ELEMENT (v_a_d_custom_filter), v_a_d_custom_filter->priv->sink");
    gst_element_add_pad (GST_ELEMENT (v_a_d_custom_filter), v_a_d_custom_filter->priv->sink);

    target = gst_element_get_static_pad (v_a_d_custom_filter->priv->cutter_filter, "src");
    GST_ERROR("src factory");
    templ = gst_static_pad_template_get (&src_factory);

    v_a_d_custom_filter->priv->src = gst_ghost_pad_new_from_template ("src", target, templ);
    g_object_unref (templ);
    g_object_unref (target);

    gst_element_add_pad (GST_ELEMENT (v_a_d_custom_filter), v_a_d_custom_filter->priv->src);
    gst_element_link (v_a_d_custom_filter->priv->audiocheb_limit, v_a_d_custom_filter->priv->cutter_filter);
}

static void
gst_v_a_d_custom_filter_class_init (GstVADCustomFilterClass *klass)
{
  GObjectClass *gobject_class = G_OBJECT_CLASS (klass);
  //GstVideoFilterClass *video_filter_class = GST_VIDEO_FILTER_CLASS (klass);

  GST_DEBUG_CATEGORY_INIT (GST_CAT_DEFAULT, PLUGIN_NAME, 0, PLUGIN_NAME);

  gst_element_class_add_pad_template (GST_ELEMENT_CLASS (klass),
                                      gst_pad_template_new ("src", GST_PAD_SRC,
                                          GST_PAD_ALWAYS,
                                          gst_caps_from_string (AUDIO_SRC_CAPS) ) );
  gst_element_class_add_pad_template (GST_ELEMENT_CLASS (klass),
                                      gst_pad_template_new ("sink", GST_PAD_SINK,
                                          GST_PAD_ALWAYS,
                                          gst_caps_from_string (AUDIO_SINK_CAPS) ) );

  gst_element_class_set_static_metadata (GST_ELEMENT_CLASS (klass),
                                      "Voice Activity Detector", "Audio/Filter",
                                      "Using GStreamer Cutter Element",
                                      "Author: Sagar Pilkhwal");

  gobject_class->finalize = gst_v_a_d_custom_filter_finalize;

  //video_filter_class->transform_frame_ip =    GST_DEBUG_FUNCPTR (gst_v_a_d_custom_filter_transform_frame_ip);

}

gboolean
gst_v_a_d_custom_filter_plugin_init (GstPlugin *plugin)
{
  GST_WARNING("Inside gst_v_a_d_custom_filter_plugin_init");
  return gst_element_register (plugin, PLUGIN_NAME, GST_RANK_NONE, GST_TYPE_V_A_D_CUSTOM_FILTER);
}
```

server log:

```
(kurento-media-server:27765): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
(kurento-media-server:27765): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_bin_add: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed
(kurento-media-server:27765): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_static_pad: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed
(kurento-media-server:27765): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_ghost_pad_new_from_template: assertion 'GST_IS_PAD (target)' failed
(kurento-media-server:27765): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
(kurento-media-server:27765): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_add_pad: assertion 'GST_IS_PAD (pad)' failed
[31;1mSegmentation fault[0m (thread [33;1m140450597959424[0m, pid [33;1m27765[0m)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that filter-factory can be only set once. Setting it twice won't work, it something that we have not tested and that can segfaults (as it seems it is happening).

If you need to apply more than just one gstreamer element, create a wrapper (GstBin) that contains both and offers the same pads interface as one simple filter (one sink and one src). Inside the GstBin you can connect as much elements as you want.

**Edit**

You can can have an example of a GstBin encapsulating various elements [here](https://github.com/Kurento/kms-filters/tree/master/src/gst-plugins/faceoverlay)

**Edit 2**

The problem is on this line:

```
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (audiocheblimit), "mode", "low-pass", NULL);
```

`"mode"` is an enum and can be passed as a string but as a integer value.

**Edit 3**

It seems that you are not declaring your element correclty on `.h` file you need:

```
 typedef _GstVADCustomFilter {
   GstBin parent;
   ...
 } GstVADCustomFilter;
```

And on your `.c` file:

```
 G_DEFINE_TYPE (GstVADCustomFilter, gst_v_a_d_custom_filter, GST_TYPE_BIN);
```

Comment: Probably you may need to define a factory for the bin. Or at least pads, otherwise the filter will reject it.

Comment: This is something similar https://github.com/Kurento/kms-filters/tree/master/src/gst-plugins/faceoverlay. I have also edited the reply with this information

Comment: I looked into `faceoverlay` example and I have edited my question.

Comment: There will probably be a stack trace at `/var/log/kurento-media-server/media-server_error.log`. Can you please give us the last one?

Comment: `(kurento-media-server:20099): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: value "((GstAudioChebLimitMode) -1913471257)" of type 'GstAudioChebLimitMode' is invalid or out of range for property 'mode' of type 'GstAudioChebLimitMode'
[31;1mSegmentation fault[0m (thread [33;1m140198495102720[0m, pid [33;1m20099[0m)`


I have used `audiocheblimit mode=low-pass`

I removed `mode=low-pass` as it is default, check my question for edit for the stack trace which I am getting now

Comment: It seems that you are passing property value incorrectly. You cannot pass the enum names as strings this way. You have to convert them (complicated) or use the numeric value (much easier).

Comment: This stack trace without debug symbols is not very usefull, why your library does not have debug symbols?

Comment: It depends on how are you loading the library in the server.

Comment: hi, issue was with `g_object_set (G_OBJECT (audiocheblimit), "cutoff", 700, NULL);` changed `700` to `700.0` but now how to I apply this bin to the `mediapipeline` or  `element` object.? `g_object_set(element, "filter-factory", "my_bin", NULL);` will need me to define a new `filter fatory` `g_object_get(G_OBJECT(element), "filter", &binfilter, NULL);`

Comment: You need to register have a factory for your element, because internally the factory is required.

Comment: also will I have to handle `sink_event` like in `faceoverlay` example `kms_image_overlay_class_init ()`

Comment: No, just connect elements and let them handle events automatically

Comment: great, can you please check my edit, I am getting segmentation fault on the server and multiple g_assert error in server log

Comment: The first line gives you the clue:
`(kurento-media-server:23094): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from 'GstVADCustomFilter' to 'GstBin'`
You are using different types than expected. Check your code.

Comment: i'm calling `GST_BIN()` for the variable which I receive from `gst_v_a_d_custom_filter_init (GstVADCustomFilter *v_a_d_custom_filter)` i.e `v_a_d_custom_filter` same as facedetector example.

Comment: The one that you have is not correct. Check it again: `struct GstVADCustomFilter {GstBin parent;....}`. And `GST_TYPE_BIN` intead of `GST_TYPE_VIDEO_FILTER`.

Comment: You have that because the autocreated files are thought for a different thing than the one you are doing. That part is OK no, but the G_DEFINE_TYPE in .c file shoud also be modified.

Comment: yes, I have changes `GST_TYPE_VIDEO_FILTER` -->`GST_TYPE_BIN`,

but now I am getting `GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid class cast from 'GstVADCustomFilter' to 'GstVideoFilter'`   :(

Comment: `GstVideoFilter base;` this should be removed from struct definition

Comment: Try checking the values returned by functions like `gst_ghost_pad_new_from_template` before using them, so you can get more specific data of what is being used incorrectly.

Comment: This is caused because the caps you are setting on your bin ar not for audio nor video and the filter element cannot autodetect. If you set to the filter that is for video or audio using `"type"` property to audio (`1`) then this should be fixed.

Comment: We are extending this thread too long, not becoming useful for others except you. Do you mind to keep your questions short and concise so can be applied to more than one user? Thanks.

Comment: sorry for that, Is there any document which I/users can refer in order to create a custom filter for kurento? because there are a lot of unknowns for a newbie... Also is there any audio processing plugin created by you available on github ?

Comment: This is the guide we used for learning how to develop GStreamer modules https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/pwg/html/ developing GStreamer modules requires a while to have a good base knowledge to be productive, please be patient.

Comment: hey hi, can you please tell how to get hold of messages posted by `cutter` element when used inside gst-plugin. I cant get a hold of `bus` on which I can add watch for messages. I just have `bin` object`. Is there any way I can attatch callback listener on the `bin` for its child elements messages

Comment: You have to wait until the element is added to a pipeline, then you can get the parent element recursively until you get null, then this is the pipeline.

Comment: okay, Is there any example which I can take a look into ? any gst-plugin which might be doing something like you said ?

Comment: None that I can remember now. Probably the closest one is zbar filter, but it does slightly differently.

Comment: hi, in kms 6.5 can we apply multiple gst-plugins in `file-factory` of kurento custom module? Earlier we used to get segfaults in KMS 6.4

Comment: No, this is not possible even in 6.5. Sorry